# Maximise the value of the minimum weight intra edge

Tags: weighted-graphs, partitions

I've been doing review problems for a midterm and I came across this one
problem that I haven't been able to solve. The problem essentially says
that given a **complete** graph $G=(V,E)$ partition the vertices into
two subsets $A$ and $B$ such that weight of the smallest intra edge
(i.e. an edge $e=(u,v)$ such that $u$ and $v$ belong to the same subset)
is maximized. The graph has $n$ vertices and $k$ weighted edges.

The edges with no weight can be assumed to have infinite weight. The
required runtime is $O((n+k) \log k)$.

I thought of this in two ways:

1. Arrange the edge weights in increasing order and for every edge
   $(u,v)$, place $u$ and $v$ in different subsets.
2. Arrange the edge weights in decreasing order and for every edge
   $(u,v)$, place $u$ and $v$ in the same subset until all the vertices
   have been placed in some subset.

The second approach doesn't work because there could be a smaller edge
among two vertices in the same subset.

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: I think that the measure to maximize is: $\min_{ (u,v) \in A^2 \cup B^2} w(u,v)$.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by the correct value? 

Also, since the graph is complete, wouldn’t it always have an odd cycle, thus making it not bipartite?

Comment: Thanks, poor reading comprehension on my part, sorry. I would delete all infinite-weight edges and use approach 1, maintaining independent bipartitions for each connected component that forms as you add weighted edges. In particular, when adding an edge $uv$ and neither $u$ nor $v$ has been considered so far, don't commit to a particular subset for them, only record that they are in different subsets within that brand new component. When adding an edge $uv$ such that $u$ and $v$ are in different existing components, the two bipartitions combine to put $u$ and $v$ on opposite sides.

Comment: Thank you so much, that’s really helpful! Any thoughts on how I could go about proving the runtime complexity?

Comment: You're welcome! Haven't thought about running time yet. Note I updated my last comment -- it's not necessary to try both ways of combining bipartitions.

Comment: I’m actually a little confused by the edit. What does “the two bipartitions combine to put u and v on opposite sides” mean? 

Also, I’m a little unsure of what you mean by maintaining independent bipartitions. Do we not add each edge as soon as we encounter it?

Comment: Sort the edges by weight, and start constructing a bipartite graph.  
The first edge you add that creates an odd cycle is the solution.

Comment: Can we assume that the edge weights are integers that are polynomially bounded w.r.t. $n$?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/48545/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/136278/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Another way to think of it is that you have just one global bipartition to which you add vertices, but any time you add an edge that connects two different connected components, you have the freedom to swap all the vertices in one of the components to the opposite part of the bipartition. You should do so iff this would put $u$ and $v$ in different parts.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to delete all of its content.

Comment: By the way, it tends to be very confusing to use any symbol other than $n$ for the number of vertices and $m$ for the number of edges for anyone who's done some work with graphs. Usually, you would expect $k$ to be some other parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G=\left(V, E=\binom{V}{2}\right)$ be your input graph, let $n=|V|$, and call $w(u,v)$ the weight of edge $(u,v) \in E$. Let $x^* = \max_{A, B} \min_{ (u,v) \in A^2 \cup B^2} w(u,v)$ be the value of an optimal solution to your problem (here $A \cup B = V$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$).

Suppose that you have a guess $x$ on the value of $x^*$ and let $D_x$ be the set of all edges of weight smaller than $x$. Consider the graph $G'=(V, D)$.

If $G'$ is bipartite, then the two sides of a bipartition will give you a partition of $V$ such that every intra-edge has weight at least $x$. This shows that $x \le x^*$.

If $G_x$ is not bipartite then, for every partition $A,B$ of $V$, you have $D_x \setminus (A \times B) \neq \emptyset$. Since the same must hold for every $x' \ge x$ (since $D_{x'} \supseteq D_x$) this shows that no partition of $G$ can have a measure of at least $x$. I.e., $x > x^*$.

You can then sort the set  $W=\{w(u,v) \mid (u,v) \in E\}$ of all edge weights and
binary search for the value of $x^* \in W$.
The binary search will require at most $O(\log n)$ iterations, and each iteration requires time $O(n^2)$ to check whether $G_x$ is bipartite.

The overall running time is then $O(n^2 \log n)$.

---

If the edges are already sorted by their weight, or if the edge weights are polynomially bounded (w.r.t. $n$) you can improve the above time complexity by a factor of almost $\Theta(\log n)$.

Indeed, if you have already conducted a bipartiteness test on $G_x$, and $G_x$ was bipartite, and then you are asked to determine whether $G_{x'}$, with $x' > x$, is bipartite there is no need to check all edges in $D_{x'}$. Indeed, you can get away with only checking the edges in $\Delta(x, x') = D_{x'} \setminus D_{x}$.

The idea is as follows: maintain a [disjoint-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) (union find) data structure $U$ on the vertices of $V$, such that if $u,v \in V$ belong to the same set in $U$, then they **must** also belong to the same side of the bipartition of the last tested graph $G_x$.

To be more precise: $U$ will contain one set $S$ for each isolated vertex of $G_x$ and two sets $S_1, S_2$ for each connected component $C$ of $G$ with at least $2$ vertices, where $S_1, S_2$ are the unique bipartition of $G$.
It is also convenient to store,  for each set $S_i$ in $U$, the name $\eta(S_i)$ of the set corresponding to the other side of the bipartition. Namely, $\eta(S_1) = S_2$ and $\eta(S_2)=S_1$.
If $S$ is a singleton set, then $\eta(S)$ is undefined.

Initially $x=0$ (assuming w.l.o.g. that all edge weights are non-negative) so $D_0 = \emptyset$ and $U$ contains $n$ singletons.

A bipartitness check on $G_{x'}$ can be done as follows: For each edge $(u,v) \in \Delta(x, x')$ query $U$ to find the sets $S_1,S_2$ such that $u \in S_1$ and $v \in S_2$. We distinguish some cases:

- **Case 1:** $S_1 = S_2$. In this case $G_{x'}$ cannot be bipartite since we already know that $u$ and $v$ must be on the same side of the bipartition.
- **Case 2:** $S_1 \neq S_2$, $\eta(S_1)$ is defined, and $\eta(S_1)=S_2$. In this case $(u,v)$ connects two vertices in different sides of the bipartition of an already existing connected component. Do nothing.
- **Case 3:** $S_1 \neq S_2$ and $\eta(S_1)$ is either undefined or $\eta(S_1) \neq S_2$. In this case we just discovered an edge across different connected components. Perform a union operation between $\eta(S_1)$ and $S_2$ and let $S'$ be the resulting set (if $\eta(S_1)$ is undefined then $S' = S_2$).
  Perform a union operation between $\eta(S_2)$ and $S_1$ and let $S''$ be the resulting set (if $\eta(S_2)$ is undefined then $S'' = S_1$).
  Set $\eta(S') = S''$ and $\eta(S'')=S'$. See the figure for an example.

[image: example_case_3]

If all edges in $\Delta(x, x')$ are processed without ever encountering case 1, then $G_{x'}$ is bipartite.

The final algorithm checks whether $G_x$ is bipartite for $x \in W$ in order, until $G_x$ becomes not bipartite. Then it returns the predecessor $y$ of $x$ in $W$. The actual partition of $V$ can be found using standard techniques (the laziest one is to find a bipartition of $G_y$ from scratch).

All the sets $\Delta(x, x')$ can be found in time $O(n^2)$ once $E$ is sorted w.r.t. $w(\cdot)$ (if $E$ is not already sorted we can use radix sort and the fact that the weights are polynomially bounded).
Moreover, the number of find operations is $O(n^2)$ and the number of union operations is $O(n)$. Thus the overall required time $O(n^2 \alpha(n))$ where $\alpha(n)$ is the inverse Ackermann function.

Notice that $\Omega(n^2)$ is a trivial lower bound for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, the algorithm could be like this:

1. Sort the $k$ edges in $k \log k$ time and notice that $n$ doesn't really factor into the running time.
2. Iteratively add one and one edge (from small to large).
3. If an edge causes an *odd cycle*, you output the value of that edge, the rest of the graph can be partitioned arbitrary.

A graph is bipartite if and only if there are no odd cycle, so in step 2 you are iteratively building a bipartite graph.  How do you quickly build up a bipartite graph?

Using [Union find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), you can merge components one component at a time, and you need to keep track of each vertex in a component whether it is "red" or "blue".  However, you need to be able to flip all colors in a component in $O(1)$ time, which should be kept as a flag in the root of a component.

Therefore, once you add an edge within a component between two vertices of the same color, you are done.

All in all, this should be doable in $O(k \log k)$ time.